# Distribution/law of a random variable after conditioning on an event

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have a probability triple $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},P)$ and a random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{B},P)\to(\mathbb R,\mathcal{R})$ with distribution $\mu_X := P \circ X^{-1}$.

If I condition on an event $E$ with $P(E) > 0$ then we get the conditional probability measure $P(\cdot|E)$ defined by

$$
P(F|E) = \frac{P(F \wedge E)}{P(E)}.
$$

The random variable $X$ becomes a conditioned random variable $(X|E)$.

> Is the conditional distribution of this conditioned random variable given by
>   $$
> \mu_{(X|E)}(F) = \frac{P(X^{-1}(F) \wedge E)}{P(E)}
> $$
>   ?

If so, we would then be able to define the conditional expectation of $(X|E)$ by

$$
\mathbb E(X|E) = \int_{\mathbb R} x \ d\mu_{(X|E)}(x).
$$

However, some books I've seen define the conditional expectation by

$$
\mathbb E(X|E) = \frac{1}{P(E)}\int X \mathbf 1_E \ dP = \frac{1}{P(E)} \int_{\mathbb R} x \ d\mu_{X \mathbf 1_E}(x).
$$

> Are these definitions equivalent?  In other words, is
>   $$
> \mu_{(X|E)} = \frac{1}{P(E)} \mu_{X\mathbf 1_E}
> $$
>   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first question, yes that is a valid equation for $\mu_{(X|E)}(F)$.

For the equivalence of the two conditional expectations, I'll first point out that the contribution for $x=0$ in the integral is $0$ so we can rewrite them as:
$$\int_{\mathbb R - \{0\}} x \ d\mu_{(X|E)}(x) = \frac{1}{P(E)} \int_{\mathbb R - \{0\}} x \ d\mu_{X \mathbf 1_E}(x)$$

The equality would be true if
$$P(X^{-1}(F) \wedge E) = P((X1_E)^{-1}({F}))$$
for all sets $F$ that do not contain $0$.  Since $1_E$ is $1$ on $E$ and zero otherwise, then $x \in (X1_E)^{-1}$ iff $X(x) \in F$ and $x \in E$.  This is the same as the set $X^{-1}(F) \wedge E$.

Comment: Hmm, how do we know that $\{0\}$ has measure $0$?  To say that $$\int_{\mathbb R} x\ d\mu_{X\mathbf{1}_E}(x) = \int_{\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}} x\ d\mu_{X\mathbf{1}_E}(x)$$ we need $$\mu_{X\mathbf{1}_E}(\{0\}) = P(X\mathbf{1}_E = 0).$$ If, for instance, $X = 1$ always, then $P(X\mathbf{1}_E = 0) = P(\overline E)$, which isn't necessarily equal to $0$.

Comment: No we don't.  That is why I removed $0$ from the integral.  But the contribution to the integral is $0$ for $x=0$ so it doesn't matter if the two measures do not agree there.

Comment: What I'm saying is that in order to remove $0$ from the integral you need to know that $\{0\}$ has measure $0$.

Comment: You don't.  Since the integrand is $x$, the contribution for $P(X = 0)$ is $0$ regardless of the size.  You can get that from the definition of the lebesgue integral.  In other words, $\int_{\{0\}} x d\mu = 0$ for all measures, even point masses.

Comment: I don't follow.  Could you cite your claim that the contribution is $0$ regardless of measure?  Because I'm looking at a book now (Bartle, *Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure*) which says (Corollary 4.11) that $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $\int_A f\,d\mu = 0$.  This is the only way I know how to conclude that we can remove $A = \{0\}$ from the domain of integration - we need $\mu_{X\mathbf{1}_E}(A) = 0$ to conclude that $\int_A f\ d\mu_{X\mathbf{1}_E} = 0$.

Comment: Consider another example: let $\mu$ be Dirac at $0$.  Then $\int_\mathbb R d\mu = 1$ but $\int_{\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}} d\mu = 0$.

Comment: That is true, but the important thing here is that the integrand is $x$.  So in your example $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x d\mu = 0$ and $\int_{\{0\}} x d\mu = 0$.

Comment: Ohhhh!  Thanks.  So yeah, $\int_{\{0\}} x\ d\mu_{X\mathbf{1}_E} = \int_{\{0\}} 0\ d\mu_{X\mathbf{1}_E} = 0 \cdot \mu_{X\mathbf{1}_E}(\{0\}) = 0.$  Got it.